# Regexp for whole words, punctuation included

Tags: mysql, regex

I'm completely new about MySQL regexp and, after 3 days searching the web I've got to give up!

I need to find words into a database, exact words. But I need to take care about punctuation too (would be nice I provide my list of punctuation symbols). These words might be at the beginning of the database record, at the end or in the middle. They also can the the only data into the record. I don't care about uppercase or lowercase words.

Thus, I need to retrieve words in such cases:

Lion - Lion. - Lion, - Lion; - Lion... (dots) - Lion… (hellip) etc. (there can be many other punctuation symbols)

or

'Lion' - "Lion" - (Lion) - <Lion> - /Lion/ etc.

but those are incorrect:

Lion.tiger - Lions - superlion - <Lion" - (Lion> - Lion.....

I've tried dozens of regexp provided on several websites but none could solve that accurately.

Cheers.

Comment: Can you please provide us few patterns that you have tried ? Have you checked something like `[a-zA-Z\.\:;\\\/\?\,\<\>\'\"\-]+` ? It will match alphabets and the mentioned characters one or more time.

Comment: Well, I think I have tested anything I could find under the name "whole word", "word with delimiters", "exact word" etc., from Stackoverflow for intance. Would be a long list... Thing is none of them provide a full example with punctuation as delimiters or just punctuation as... punctuation.

Comment: your explanation was good until I realized that `<Lion>` was valid and `<Lion" - (Lion>` was not. This sent us outside REGEXP realm, if I remember my CS courses well.

Comment: @Julien you didn't bother to read the full problem, right?

Comment: Please explain exactly why some patterns pass and others fail

Comment: Yes, I'm afraid it goes beyond REGEXP... A lot a work ahead

Comment: What is it exactly you're trying to do? The phrasings do not make sense in terms of searches. Are these in the context of words, are you trying to find a specific custom tag? I don't understand basis for the search parameters.

Comment: Doesn't make sense? At least, it makes sense for my project, using several languages. It's legal, with many languages to use "lions" for example. In French, it's not correct, we should write « Lions » (with spaces). Other example, in Spanish you may find ¿leones? (no spaces). Etc. I often run across search engines not using punctuation signs correctly too. I can't afford such crappy programming with my project. I need to retrieve words according to all particular cases mentioned above. Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use word boundaries. Otherwise you'll have to declare all of the characters that you're willing to accept.

```
select id,myRecord from my_records where myRecord REGEXP '[[:<:]]lion[[:>:]]';
```

Here's an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d80d2/14) using some of the examples that you've provided for matching.

Note that because the `.` character in Lion.tiger is typically considered a word barrier (end of sentence declaration) in English, you might need to make a special case where you're not matching it.

```
select id,myRecord from my_records where
myRecord REGEXP '[[:<:]]lion[[:>:]]' and
myRecord NOT REGEXP '[[:<:]]lion\.[[:alpha:]]';
```

[Example fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d80d2/15).

Comment: I've played with [[:<:]] but even if main cases can be solved, there are many problems. How to avoid, for instance, <Lion< or Lion.. (2 dots) to be retrieved? I don't mind declaring all the characters accepted, how would you do that?